# When working with php in Wordpress what do the "=>" and "__" symbols mean?

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I am looking at using a custom Taxonomy for a page and [reading through the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) I saw code examples using "=>" and "__"

Could someone clarify what these symbols are for and what they are doing?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate as the second *symbol* referenced does have a specific usage in WordPress ([internationalization function](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)).

Comment: there's no option for 50% duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=>` is used for defining the value of a key in an associative array:

```
$array = array('key' => 'value');
```

The `__()` function is used for translations:

```
$text = __($textkey, $textdomain);
```